# Как посчитать вероятность?

Tags: python

Есть ли какой ни будь вариант побыстрее то перебором всех случаев как-то медленно. Искал в формулу в интернете, не нашел.

Вот мой вариант:

```
def choise(in_all, need):
    count = 0
    for i in range(2 * 2 ** (in_all - 1)):
        if bin(i)[2:].count('1') == need:
            count += 1
    return 1 / count * 100
print(choise(5,2))
```

Пример использование кода:

Какие корни у уравнения x^2+3x-4=0. Выберите 2 верных ответа:

1. 0
2. 1
3. 4
4. -4
5. -1

Вероятность того что выбрав наугад вы ответите правильно: 10%

Comment: По-моему, тут 10%, а не 6,66%.

Comment: Формулу надо искать не в интернете, а в учебнике по основам теории вероятностей. Это самые азы. И непонятно, вероятность чего нужно посчитать.

Comment: У вас есть вопрос, и 5 вариантов ответа, и вы знаете что 2 ответа правильны. И надо рассчитать какая вероятность что вы ответите  правильно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В перечне 2 правильных ответа из  5 (ваше уравнения я даже не смотрел, решаем чисто вероятностную задачу). Вероятность того, что первый ответ вы угадали -  2/5. После этого у вас осталось 4 варианта для второго шага. Вероятность угадать - 1/4. Итого
0.4*0.25=0.1.

И вам правильно сказали. Искать в интернете надо ПОСЛЕ того, как вы хоть что-то изучили по книгам.